# Simple way to stream from php to HTML5 audio tag and allowing the audio to be seekable?

Tags: php, html, audio

I currently have this

```
<audio id ="player">
    <source src="includes/playsong.php" id = "player">
</audio>
```

JS

```
var playsong = function (songName) {
    $('#playing').html(songName);
    if (currentSong === songName) {
        return;
    }
    $.post('includes/songrequest.php', {'request': songName}, function () {
        $('#source').attr("src", "includes/playsong.php/" + songName);
        player.load();
        play();
    });

$('#slider').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    step: 0.001,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        player.currentTime = player.duration * ui.value;

        }
}
```

And the PHP

```
$file = mysqli_fetch_assoc($song)['location'];
header('Content-Type: audio/' . pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
readfile($file);
```

The php gets the song location from a table if the user actually owns the song using the path. The code is currently waiting for the whole file to load before playing or even skipping tracks even though I allowed ranges. Is there another way to send the right chunks without waiting for the whole thing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe try outputting file in chunks by hand?

```
set_time_limit(0);
$file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
while(!feof($file)) {
    print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

I found this code snippet here http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/. Hope it helps

Comment: You should be slapped for using `@`